# LINQ Option Built Query + DateTime Comparision

Tags: c#, linq

This straightforward query works and returns the expected 4 records;

```cs
var showIfAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var query = _context.OTMLessons.Where(l => l.Date > showIfAfter);
```

This piecemeal built query doesn't (assume status == A);

```cs
var query = _context.OTMLessons.Include("Years").Include("Giver")
    .Where(l => !l.Hidden);

if (status != null)
    switch (status) {
        case "A":
            // only records that are current (last day plus important states)
            var showIfAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            query = query.Where(l => l.Date > showIfAfter);
            break;
        case "ND":
            // only records which aren't deleted
            query = query.Where(l => !l.Status.Equals("Deleted"));
            break;
        default:
            // records of a specific state
            query = query.Where(l => l.Status.Equals(status));
            break;
    }
```

Please tell my why I'm an idiot - pulling my hair out...

Comment: Are you sure that `.Wherel => !l.Hidden)` is correct? What does `_context.OTMLessons._context.OTMLessons.Where(l => !l.Hidden)` return?

Comment: Removed as irrelevant to question; break-point pre-execution of showIfAfter comparison reveals expected results

Comment: Without seeing more code this is hard to debug. Are you 100% sure that status "A" is being correctly set? That would cause you to not get the correct data.

Comment: In your first example, if you change to var query = _context.OTMLessons.Include("Years").Include("Giver")
    .Where(l => !l.Hidden && l.Date > showIfAfter); Do you still get the expected 4 records

Comment: Just tested and yes :( Perhaps time for bed...

Comment: After the switch, use ToString() on your query to see its description exactly

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in the `Include()`.

```cs
var query = _context.OTMLessons.Where(l => !l.Hidden);

if (status != null)
    switch (status) {
        case "A":
            // only records that are current (last day plus important states)
            var showIfAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            query = query.Where(l => l.Date > showIfAfter).Include("Years").Include("Giver");
            break;
        case "ND":
            // only records which aren't deleted
            query = query.Where(l => !l.Status.Equals("Deleted")).Include("Years").Include("Giver");
            break;
        default:
            // records of a specific state
            query = query.Where(l => l.Status.Equals(status)).Include("Years").Include("Giver");
            break;
    }
```

Might seem a bit verbose; but it should include the subset collections once it figures out the Date/Status fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries are different. The first one says:

```
_context.OTMLessons.Where(l => l.Date > showIfAfter);
```

The second one says (eventually:

```
_context.OTMLessons.Include("Years").Include("Giver")
.Where(l => !l.Hidden && l.Date > showIfAfter);
```

You should check which difference is causing the change in the results. First try to make them exactly the same and then start adding more criteria. Then you can check where the result changes and verify your data.